# Repeated values with GROUP_CONCAT without using DISTINCT on MySQL query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct, group-concat

I have a schema like the one below and I'm trying to make a query to get all filters and all project_items from a single project, so that the results are just in one line by using GROUP_CONCAT.

### filters

- id
- title

### project_filters

- id
- filters_id
- projects_id

### projects

- id
- title

### project_items

- id
- title
- projects_id

### the tables are connected like this

[filters] 1--N [project_filters] N--1 [projects] 1--N [project_items]

### the query and the problem

- SELECT
- projects.id,
- projects.title,
- GROUP_CONCAT(project_items.title) AS items_title,
- GROUP_CONCAT(filters.title) AS filters_title
- FROM projects
- LEFT JOIN project_items ON project_items.projects_id=projects.id
- LEFT JOIN project_filters ON projects.id=project_filters.projects_id
- LEFT JOIN filters ON filters.id=project_filters.filters_id
- WHERE projects.id="1"

Project 1 has 3 filters (1, 2 and 3) and 3 items (1, 2 and 3), which is resulting in repeated values (9 for each), like this:

- id = 1
- title = project 1
- items_title = title 1, title 2, title 3, title 1, title 2, title 3, title 1, title 2, title 3
- filters_title = filter 1, filter 2, filter 3, filter 1, filter 2, filter 3, filter 1, filter 2, filter 3

#### Can anybody point me in the right direction? I would like to know how to make the query return the filters and items without repeating.

I think the solution is to arrange the joins somehow, but I can't figure it out.

**OBS: GROUP_CONCAT with DISTINCT doesn't fit because there might be repeating titles**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subqueries for each of GROUP_CONCATs:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.items_title, f.filters_title FROM
( SELECT
  projects.id,
  projects.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(project_items.title) AS items_title
  FROM projects
  LEFT JOIN project_items ON project_items.projects_id=projects.id
  group by projects.id,
  projects.title) as i
INNER JOIN
( SELECT
  projects.id,
  projects.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(filters.title) AS filters_title
  FROM projects
  LEFT JOIN project_filters ON projects.id=project_filters.projects_id
  LEFT JOIN filters ON filters.id=project_filters.filters_id
  group by projects.id,
  projects.title) as f
ON i.id = f.id
WHERE i.id="1"
```

Comment: thank you @cha, but now what I get is:

**id =** 1
**title =** project 1
**items_title =** title 1, title 2, title 3, title 1, title 2, title 3
**filters_title =** filter 1, filter 2, filter 2, filter 3, filter 3

but you gave me some ideas, I'm gonna try to implement them and report back! thank you!

Comment: Ok, forgot group by. Try this solution. Please note that my solution as opposed to yours will work correctly without the last where clause

Comment: yes, now it works! I also forgot to put the group by that I used in my solution, gonna update it for others...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All right, with @cha's answer (thanks mate) and some more research, I got the right result by removing the INNER JOIN between the two queries.

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.items_title, f.filters_title FROM
( SELECT
  projects.id,
  projects.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(project_items.title) AS items_title
  FROM projects
  LEFT JOIN project_items ON project_items.projects_id=projects.id
  WHERE projects.id="1"
  GROUP BY projects.id) AS i,
( SELECT
  projects.id,
  projects.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(filters.title) AS filters_title
  FROM projects
  LEFT JOIN project_filters ON projects.id=project_filters.projects_id
  LEFT JOIN filters ON filters.id=project_filters.filters_id
  WHERE projects.id="1"
  GROUP BY projects.id) AS f
WHERE i.id=f.id
```